# Can´t use an union element inside a nested structure as argument for scanf() to store desired value

Tags: c++, c, nested, scanf, unions

I have a problem about to use scanf with an union element as an argument which superior union is part of a nested structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    typedef union { float chair; int bed; } HABITATION;
    typedef struct { HABITATION room; int number; } HOUSE;

    scanf("%d",&HOUSE.room.bed);
}
```

The error message from the compiler is :
"Error: expected expression before ) >>ROOF<<".

What have i done wrong?

INFO:
I currently use C but i am also interested for the same operation and answer in/ for C++.

Comment: The reason is the same in both languages, and is the same, as why `scanf("%d",&int);` is invalid.

Comment: Where is `ROOF` in the code?

Comment: The C++ code can look quite different and applies different rules to `union`s. The comparison between the two would be a good question on its own and shouldn't be a sidebar here.

Comment: Note that `HOUSE` is not a variable, it's a type, so you can't pass any of its members to `scanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, that was the problem. I confused it were a variable and did not mind it was still a datatype. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know C, but in C++ your code should be equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union HABITATION { float chair; int bed; };
struct HOUSE { HABITATION room; int number; };

int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&HOUSE.room.bed);
}
```

Maybe now it is obvious that you merely defined two types, but you never create an instance of anything in this code. `HOUSE` is a type not an instance.

In c++ you would do

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   HOUSE h; 
   std::cin >> h.room.bed;
}
```

And probably not use all CAPITAL names. Some use them for globals, I am more on the side of banning them completely. Names should speak for themself, no need to shout. `House` is clear enough if you use first letter capital for classes and all small letters for instances (eg `house`). Thats also what Stroustrup suggests in [his guideline](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP-style.pdf).

Comment: Yes, that was the case.I confused it were a variable and did not mind it was still a datatype. @WeatherVane has found that, too. Thank you very much, both of you. Thank you very much also for the additional answer and informations.